# How to create anorm's parser with array?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, anorm

I am using postgresql which supports array column field. To parse a row, I use this parser. It has error at the Array object. I guess I did it wrongly.

```
case class ServiceRequest(
  id: Pk[Long],
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  images: Array[String])

val parser: RowParser[ServiceRequest] = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("id") ~
      get[String]("firstname") ~
      get[String]("lastname") ~
      Error here >>> get[Array[String]]("images") map {
        case id ~ firstname ~ lastname ~ images=>
          ServiceRequest(id, firstname, lastname, images)
      }
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: This is just a guess, I'm new to scala & anorm, but have you tried Seq[String] ?

Comment: I tried Seq and List. Both the same. I just found a solution that is creating a custom extractor for the parser.

Comment: Could you post it? I'm sure it would be helpful to others, including, but not limited to me :)

Comment: sure, I will after finished the codes and tested it to make sure that it works properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my problem by adding this converter:

```
implicit def rowToStringArray: Column[Array[String]] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
    val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
    value match {
      case o: java.sql.Array => Right(o.getArray().asInstanceOf[Array[String]])
      case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass))
    }
  }
```

The converter transforms data type from postgresql's jdbc to java's data type for the parser in SELECT function. When you insert, you need another converter to convert from java's data type to postgresql's jdbc.

Comment: Awesome!!!! Until 2.4 comes out (which I believe will have support for arrays) this is and will work nicely!!!!

Answer (score 5):

The `Array[T]` type is now natively supported in play 2.4.x, your don't have to roll your own converters.
But, it's still not nice to work with insert or update statements like:

```
def updateTags(id: Long, values: Seq[String]):Int = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
      SQL("UPDATE entries SET tags = {value} WHERE id = {id}")
        .on('value -> values, 'id -> id).executeUpdate
}
```

will give you an error

> play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"

Put it simply, you should create the `PreparedStatement` using `java.sql.Array` type:

`on('value -> conn.createArrayOf("varchar", value.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]), ...`

As of now (play 2.4-M1), `java.sql.Array` is not converted to `ParameterValue` by default, which means
`` SQL(...).on(`arr -> values:java.sql.Array ) `` still gives a compilation error, you need another implicit conversion to make it compiling:

```
  implicit object sqlArrayToStatement extends ToStatement[java.sql.Array] {
    def set(s: PreparedStatement, i: Int, n: java.sql.Array) = s.setArray(i, n)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a pullrequest to add support for java.sql.Array as column mapping: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3062 .

Best,

Comment: PR is merged on master

Comment: As you can see in test/specs, feature is included in latest sources: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/test/scala/anorm/ColumnSpec.scala#L290